# What is the intended way of reliably receiving all TCP packets in an asio server

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, asio

I have a simple TCP-server that accepts connections asynchronously

```
m_acceptor.async_accept( m_socket, [this]( const boost::system::error_code error )
                                   {
                                     if( error )
                                     {
                                       stop(); //member function
                                     }
                                     else
                                     {
                                       do_async_read();
                                     });
```

What is the intended way of performing a robust async_read without any packet loss( atleast 9 out of 10 times ) . Following is my attempt which does not produce reliable and consistent results on subsequent runs of my test application .

```
void do_async_read()
{
  boost::asio::async_read( m_socket, boost::asio::buffer( &m_buffer[0], 1500 ),
      boost::asio::transfer_at_least( m_payload_len ),
      [this]( const boost::system::error_code error, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
       {
          if ( !error )
          {
             m_pkt_recv_count += 1;
             do_async_read();
          }
          else
          {
            stop();
          }
      } );
}
```

I have a client application which has the following features:

- Connects to TCP server
- Ability to configure payload_len. For my test, payload_len = 100
- Generate random payloads of payload_len
- Control the number of packets sent to the server.
- Control the speed at which packets of payload_len = 100 are sent to the server

For the easy test-case which performs consistently on subsequent runs:

- Number of Packets sent = 5
- Packets are sent at a rate of 1 per second
- Result : m_pkt_recv_count = 5 at the end of the test as expected

Test-Case 2:

- Number of Packets sent = 5
- Packets are sent at a rate of 1 per 8 micro-seconds
- Result : m_pkt_recv_count = 2 most of the times when it should be 5. Very few times it becomes 5.

Hypothesis:

- There is no packet-loss at the kernel level for a fact because tcpdump on the client side produces 5 frames containing ACKs apart from the handshake during session establishment.
- Moreover the interface on the server side shows 0 dropped packets when using ifconfig server_intf
- tcpdump on the server-side verifies all 5 packets are reaching the server
- Additionally if I change my completion-condition function object from transfer_at_least( m_payload_len ) to transfer_at_least( 5 * m_payload_len ), I receive all the bytes once

All the above points me to the fact that some-bytes are going missing on subsequent calls to do_asyn_read, but I am unable to put my finger on exactly what it might be. I have tried to use m_socket.async_receive instead of async_read, but get pretty much similar results .

Any help/insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I bet `bytes_transferred` is > 100 in these cases. Your mistake is to assume you get exactly 100 bytes each time.

Comment: @tkasul actually asio::async_read reads the requested number of bytes unless an error occurs: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html. socket.async_read does return less than the requested amount, asio::async_read calls socket.async_read repeatedly until the requested amount is read.

Comment: how many threads have you assigned to your io_service? is m_pkt_recv_count atomic? if not then incrementing it is not safe and will miss some packets.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I don't see a parameter for the number of bytes in `async_read`, and the parameter `boost::asio::transfer_at_least` explicitly says _at least_, not _exactly_ .

Comment: whoops, I hadn't seen transfer_at_least on the next line(@john-smith formatting is important to code readability), without that parameter async_read would continue until the buffer is full

Comment: @tkausl is correct. The number of bytes > 100 which explains the behavior, my assumption of getting exactly 100 bytes was incorrect.  There is no packet/byte loss. Thanks